# Possible to make a REST call within geth console?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, testnets, nodejs

I want to listen to events on a contract and then send them to a rest endpoint.

1. Is it possible to make a REST call within the geth console?
2. Alternatively, if I have a node application and I load web3, how can I connect to the testnet?

Comment: Consider making the answer as accepted, you can do it by checking the tick sign under votes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make `REST` calls from `geth console` specifically JavaScript Console of go-ethereum

As explained in the official [how to](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#how-to)

> It is possible to specify the set of API's which are offered over an
>   interface with the `--${interface}api` command line argument for the go
>   ethereum daemon. Where `${interface}` can be rpc for the http interface
>   or ipc for an unix socket on unix or named pipe on Windows.

To determine which API's an interface provides the modules transaction can be used, e.g. over an ipc interface on unix systems:

```
echo '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"modules","params":[],"id":1}' | nc -U $datadir/geth.ipc
```

connection to testnet is made by geth not the web3 interface. and web3 is used to any geth instance irrespective of whether is testate or live.

Read [Connecting to the network](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#custom-networks)

the method would be `geth -—networkid="12345" console` you can read more on the custom genesis block etc in the wiki.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, in my geth client, if I've started it with jsonrpc for its communication to ethereum, that api is available to my own code running within geth to do my own calls to other non-ethereum rest servers? (I want to record contract events over a rest call to some other server)

Comment: @JamesB There is no need to query other serve, your node is in `sync` with all other nodes, that is by design.

Comment: I want to make a rest call (using javascript) to a different, non-ethereum service to record events from the blockchain (not to a different geth node)  the code to listen to the event is in my local geth node and then calls externally to the blockchain over http

Comment: You can use `loadScript` function of geth javascript console to load a regular javascript file to the console and execute functions. try that way.

Comment: Thanks, although it looks like neither the `XMLHttpRequest` class nor the http module is available, so it doesn't look like this is going to fly.  I should just be able to run geth locally that connects to the testnet and then run I can up a node app which loads `web3.js` and connects to geth as the gateway and then does all my rest and blockchain interactivity, right?

Comment: @JamesB Yeah, thats right. I was mistaken. including `web3.js` into your own html file or a node app will work fine.